# Detecting the last record in a for loop

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a series of loops that put together a clob from a table of data in a weird pseudo-json format.

The issue I have is that each of these loops needs to end out the section with the relevant character, but I am unable to figure out how to identify the last record.

So far, I have:

```
for y in (select distinct ident from table(an_object))
loop
  pseudojson := pseudojson || '{';

  the_row := y.ident;
  for z in (select * from table(an_object) where ident = the_row)
    loop
    pseudojson := pseudojson || z.the_key ||': "' || z.the_value ||'"';
    -- (1)
    end loop;

  pseudojson := pseudojson || '}';
  -- (2)
end loop;

pseudojson := pseudojson || '}';
```

`an_object` contains the unpivoted data, grouped into the former rows by `ident`.

For logic, I'm trying to shoehorn in the following

(1)

```
if not z.last 
then 
  pseudojson := pseudojson || ','; 
end if;
```

and (2)

```
if not y.last
then 
  pseudojson := pseudojson || ','; 
end if;
```

but these operators do not work in the for loop.

Can anyone give me a steer in the right direction?

Comment: And what if in the case of last record. How it should look like

Comment: @XING If it's the last, do nothing, exit loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this. You need a boolean variable:

```
first := true;
```

Inside the loop:

```
if not first then
    pseudojson := pseudojson || ','; 
end if;
first := false;
-- Add the element
...
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this: do whatever you do, concatenate *usual* characters within the loop, including the "last" row.

Once you EXIT the loop, `RTRIM` the superfluous character (a comma, right?). Something like this:

```
for y in (select distinct ident from table(an_object))
loop
  pseudojson := pseudojson || '{';

  the_row := y.ident;
  for z in (select * from table(an_object) where ident = the_row)
    loop
    pseudojson := pseudojson || z.the_key ||': "' || z.the_value ||'"';
    -- (1)
    pseudojson := pseudojson ||',';
    end loop;

    pseudojson := rtrim(pseudojson, ',');  --> this

  pseudojson := pseudojson || '}';
  -- (2)
  pseudojson := pseudojson ||',';
end loop;

pseudojson := rtrim(pseudojson, ',');      --> this
pseudojson := pseudojson || '}';
```